# lenovo (p52) overheating, how one can fix that?

Tags: cpu, lenovo-laptop, cooling, temperature

I found out, that my laptop cpu is overheating and stock fan can't do much about it. Some data: Idling, the cpu temperature is around 50°C and cpu is running at 800Mhz, while its max is 4000Mhz. Now I run `stress -c 12`. Temp is immediately over 90°C, while cpu clock is now around 3500Mhz, so not even max. Few seconds and kernel is saving cpu from it's death by throttling it down to 800Mhz (the minimum freq), while the load is still the same. So what does it actually mean: the company paid for quite performant laptop, which! can produce the heavy lifting its stats promised only for few seconds and then it performs as much cheaper machine.

I don't believe some external fan will help, since with load the temperature increase is immediate ~ there is problem with getting heat away from cpu, not further from the case.

Can this be a faulty piece? Or is this a lenovo standard, to have suicidal cpu working top for few seconds only?

Comment: Was the device new from Lenovo? If not, then it's worth checking the airvents are clear... since that will be the simplest fix.

Comment: @Stese like 2 weeks old, brand new directly from shop

Comment: Are you running it with the power connected? Many laptops throttle the fan speed when on battery to save said battery...

Comment: on AC line. I mean — it's complicated here. I have these values when running on Thunderbolt docking station (which I also use as a pad to lift laptop from the table to get it some fresh air). And when in this docking station, the P52 have 2 AC adapter connected: 230W and 65W at the same time. However the slot where 65W charger is connected to is marked as 135/65W so maybe there should be stronger than provided AC? I don't know. But ... 295W should be sufficient for coolant system. ~~I can retry to measure in different conditions, but current ones should be the normal/ideal ones IIUC.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with the cooling system.  It it has a warrant exchange it or have them fix it.  It almost as if the plate that makes contact with the CPU to transfer the heat away is either not in contact or only partially in contact.  You could find said part and touch it or use a thermometer, because if your CPU is 90C it should be nearly as hot.

Comment: @cybernard thank for "confirmation" of my gut feeling "something isn't right"; I'll try to run bios hw health/performance tests and regardless of outcome I'll contact business support on monday. Thx!

Comment: @Martin Mucha so I tried "hw tests" in bios and they all passed. One of them was so called cpu stress test, but that one was most stress-free stress test I ever saw. Like the fan did not even start spinning and there was almost no heat coming out of case. IE. lenovo hw self test is very optimistic. Launching chrome is far bigger stress test, than actual lenovo stress test. So yes, the bios hw testing passed, but it more or less looks like, it was designed to do so.